# How to restrict zoom on some element of svg in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I Created SVG using D3.js and added 3 points. The points contains text and image.

And also the line which connects these points.

```
        g.insert("g");
        var text = g2.selectAll("text")
         .data(formattedTopoData.features);

        var mark = g2.selectAll("image")
        .data(formattedTopoData.features);

        var link = g.selectAll(".line_DEFAULT")
        .data(formattedTopoData.links);
```

And i have attached zoom callback like this

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
     .translate([0, 0])
     .scale(1)
     .scaleExtent([1, 8])
     .on("zoom", function(){

        //svg.selectAll("path")
        g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");

        //svg.selectAll("path").
        g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");};
```

Now when I zoom the 3 objects (line ,text,image) are getting zoomed.

I want to restrict the zoom of image and text.

Plz help.
Image lookes like this
[image]

I have created plunker : [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2wwXrCp9tR6AqlPVPWaE?p=preview)
Here I want to zoom map with text. but I don't want text to be look big when zoomed

Comment: Scale the projection and not the SVG as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340).

Comment: If I Scale the projection , points/nodes are not moving but map is moving/zooming

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2wwXrCp9tR6AqlPVPWaE?p=preview  here you can see example i want test(text added) to be zoomed with map but test(text added) should not scale

Comment: You have to reset the positions of everything that uses the projection as well http://plnkr.co/edit/VYwI8vEuLKPKozdcg1Ox?p=preview